# do starting a youtube video production require huge budget

Tags: youtube

We want to start our own 1st youtube channel we will create in house videos from hd camera but before that we need to get an estimation of capital required in video production anyone who is well aware and already own a channel please give us some tips

thank u in advance

Comment: Video production can cost 0 (the team pays it all), 50 (hey, burgers for everybody), 1,000 (cool, we can hire a sound producer and more), 10,000 (your van will pick you up at 7AM)... etc...

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to your question is "No, starting a YouTube video channel does not require a huge budget."  There are YouTube channels that consist only of videos made using smartphones.

If you want to shoot for higher production values than that, you should be more specific in your question and you might get a more specific answer.  But the simple answer is: if you have a smartphone with video capabilities, you can start a YouTube channel with just that.

Comment: hi there thank u for your reply but the visual effects, animation, etc some people put on their videos are not only from smartphone camera if i m right they are using some software or any other service to achieve these can u suggest something more tools

Comment: There are at least 5 free tools that can do visual effects, animation, etc: http://opensource.com/life/15/1/current-state-linux-video-editing